# MVC Application using WebApi, Identity, and using Cookies safely

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I had the requirement to have my Identity-enabled MVC site with WebApi use cookies for authentication for both the site and web api.  Anyone who has dealt with this probably knows that this could be vulnerable to XSS attacks as the regular login cookie could be sent to your webapi methods by visiting a malicious page.

The strange requirement to use cookies with web api is the root of the matter.  Is there any way to do this safely?

I have a solution using Forms Authentication in an `AuthorizationFilter` (posted below) but I was hoping to leverage the features of the Identity framework such as claims and sign-out everywhere.

```
using System;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Filters
{

    /// <summary>
    /// An authentication filter that uses forms authentication cookies.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>Use the *Cookie static methods to manipulate the cookie on the client</remarks>
    public class FormsAuthenticationFilter : Attribute, IAuthenticationFilter
    {

        public static long Timeout { get; set; }
        public static string CookieName { get; set; }

        public FormsAuthenticationFilter()
        {
            // Default Values
            FormsAuthenticationFilter.Timeout = FormsAuthentication.Timeout.Minutes;
            FormsAuthenticationFilter.CookieName = "WebApi";
        }


        public FormsAuthenticationFilter(long Timeout, string CookieName)
        {
            FormsAuthenticationFilter.Timeout = Timeout;
            FormsAuthenticationFilter.CookieName = CookieName;

        }

        public Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

            HttpRequestMessage request = context.Request;

            // Get cookie
            HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthenticationFilter.CookieName];

            //If no cookie then do nothing
            if (cookie == null)
            {
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }

            //If empty cookie then raise error
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(cookie.Value))
            {
                context.ErrorResult = new AuthenticationFailureResult("Empty ticket", request);
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }

            //Decrypt ticket
            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = default(FormsAuthenticationTicket);

            try
            {
                authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                context.ErrorResult = new AuthenticationFailureResult("Invalid ticket", request);
                return Task.FromResult(0);

            }

            //Check if expired

            if (authTicket.Expired)
            {
                context.ErrorResult = new AuthenticationFailureResult("Ticket expired", request);
                return Task.FromResult(0);

            }

            //If caching roles in userData field then extract
            string[] roles = authTicket.UserData.Split(new char[] { '|' });

            // Create the IIdentity instance
            IIdentity id = new FormsIdentity(authTicket);

            // Create the IPrinciple instance
            IPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(id, roles);

            // Set the context user 
            context.Principal = principal;

            // Update ticket if needed (sliding window expiration)
            if ((authTicket.Expiration - DateTime.Now).TotalMinutes < (FormsAuthenticationFilter.Timeout / 2))
            {
                RenewCookie(authTicket);

            }

            return Task.FromResult(0);

        }

        public Task ChallengeAsync(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {

            //Do nothing
            return Task.FromResult(0);

        }

        public bool AllowMultiple
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Renews the cookie on the client using the specified FormsAuthenticationTicket
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="OldTicket">A still-valid but aging FormsAuthenticationTicket that should be renewed</param>
        /// <remarks></remarks>
        protected static void RenewCookie(FormsAuthenticationTicket OldTicket)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(GetCookie(OldTicket.Name, OldTicket.UserData));

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the authentication cookie on the client
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="UserName">The username to set the cookie for</param>
        /// <remarks></remarks>
        public static void SetCookie(String user, IList<string> roles)
        {

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(GetCookie(user, string.Join("|", roles)));

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Removes the authentication cookie on the client
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>Cookie is removed by setting the expires property to in the past, may not work on all clients</remarks>
        public static void RemoveCookie()
        {
            if ((HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies[FormsAuthenticationFilter.CookieName] != null))
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies[FormsAuthenticationFilter.CookieName].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
            }

        }

        private static HttpCookie GetCookie(string UserName, string UserData)
        {

            //Create forms auth ticket
            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, UserName, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(FormsAuthenticationFilter.Timeout), false, UserData);

            //Create cookie with encrypted contents
            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthenticationFilter.CookieName, FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket));
            cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(FormsAuthenticationFilter.Timeout);

            //Return it
            return cookie;

        }

        protected class AuthenticationFailureResult : IHttpActionResult
        {

            public AuthenticationFailureResult(string reasonPhrase, HttpRequestMessage request)
            {
                this.ReasonPhrase = reasonPhrase;
                this.Request = request;
            }

            public string ReasonPhrase { get; set; }
            public HttpRequestMessage Request { get; set; }

            public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                return Task.FromResult(Execute());
            }

            private HttpResponseMessage Execute()
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
                response.RequestMessage = Request;
                response.ReasonPhrase = ReasonPhrase;
                return response;
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me preface this answer by saying this is only a solution if **WebApi methods are never called via javascript from your website**.  This should only be used if you plan to use WebApi from other clients such as a mobile app.

The solution lies in using a separate cookie for WebApi.  WebApi will reject the normal site authorization cookie and only use its own.

In your `WebApiConfig` class add a constant and a static method to configure the cookie middle-ware:

```
public const string WebApiCookieAuthenticationType = "WebApiCookie";

public static CookieAuthenticationOptions CreateCookieAuthenticationOptions()
{

     return new CookieAuthenticationOptions
     {
        AuthenticationType = WebApiConfig.WebApiCookieAuthenticationType,
        AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Passive,
        CookieName = ".AspNet.WebApiCookie",
        CookiePath = "/api",
        ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
        SlidingExpiration = true,
        LoginPath = new PathString("/api/auth"),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        {
            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60),
                regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => manager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, WebApiConfig.WebApiCookieAuthenticationType)
            ),
             OnApplyRedirect = ctx => {}
        }
    };

}
```

Note the `AuthenticationType` and `AuthenticationMode`, these will prevent it from interfering with normal site cookies after we register it.  We do this next in your `Startup` class placing it just below the existing `app.UseCookieAuthentication()` call:

```
// Setup WebApi Cookie Authentication
app.UseCookieAuthentication(WebApiConfig.CreateCookieAuthenticationOptions());
```

We also need to configure WebApi to ignore the normal site cookies and process our special cookies as well.  Do this in your `WebApiConfig.Register()` method:

```
// Ignore website auth
config.SuppressHostPrincipal();
config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(WebApiCookieAuthenticationType));
```

Now we are setup but how do you issue the auth cookie?  Create an authorization controller method in your webapi that uses the standard Identity `SignInManager` but with an extra step:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Authenticate(string userName, string password)
{

    // Get signIn manager
    var signInManager = HttpContext.Current.Request.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
    if (signInManager == null)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
    // Important!
    signInManager.AuthenticationType = WebApiConfig.WebApiCookieAuthenticationType;

    // Sign In
    var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(userName, password, false, shouldLockout: true);
    if (result == SignInStatus.Success)
    {

        // Return
        return Ok();

    }

    // Failure
    return BadRequest();

}
```

Pay particular attention to where we set the `SignInManager`'s `AuthenticationType`, this will make it use our special WebApi cookie instead of the standard site cookie.

### Gotchas

One gotcha is that the default site template overrides the `SignInManager`'s `CreateUserIdentityAsync` method with a hard-coded reference to `DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie` authentication type.  This will interfere with this solution.  To fix it you can change the override to this:

```
public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user)
{
    if (this.AuthenticationType == DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie)
    {
        return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager);
    }
    else
    {
        return base.CreateUserIdentityAsync(user);
    }

}
```

Another gotcha is compression.  If you are using the great `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Extensions.Compression` package you will need to disable compression for web api methods using the `SignInManager` to log in/out as it writes the response before Identity can add the Set-Cookie header to the response.